# C++ compilation errors in header

Tags: c++, header, codeblocks

Just a heads up, this is a school assignment, but it is not graded.

I was provided these 4 source code files, but the header seems to be holding me back with string/function errors etc.

This was built in Codeblocks

super.h

```
    class super
{
public:
    ///default constructor
    super(){}
    ///alternate constructor
    super(string i, string a, string m, string l)
        {Ident = i; Alias = a; MState=m; Location=l;}
    ///destructor
    ~super(){cout<<"BOING!! Hero Disappears"<<endl;}

    ///mutators  -- Sets
    void setIdent(string i){Ident = i;}
    void setAlias(string a){Alias = a;}
    void setMState(string m){MState = m;}
    void setLocation(string l){Location = l;}


    ///accessors  -- Gets
    string getIdent(){return Ident;}
    string getAlias(){return Alias;}
    string getMState(){return MState;}
    string getLocation(){return Location;}

    ///other functionality  -- declared here, defined in impl file
    void display();
    void changeLoc();

private:
    string Ident;
    string Alias;
    string MState;
    string Location;

};
```

super_impl.cpp

```
///first.....go find the definition of a super.
#include "super.h"

///this file contains the "guts" of
///functions too large to be in the header.
///this is apart of the definition of a SUPER
///a void function display that follows an instance of super
void super::display()
{
    cout<<"The Amazing "<<Alias<<endl;
    cout<<"Mild Mannered "<<Ident<<" seeks ";
    cout<<MState<<endl;
    cout<<"Currently found at "<<Location<<endl<<endl;
}

void super::changeLoc()
{   string stemp;
    cout<<"Where is "<<Alias<<" going?"<<endl;
    getline(cin,stemp);
    Location = stemp;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

super_test_1.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "super_impl.cpp"

int main()
{
    super S1;
    S1.display();

    S1.setIdent("Robby Williams");
    S1.setAlias("Snail");
    S1.setMState("To Protect Invertebrates Everywhere");
    S1.setLocation("His secret lair under the rock");

    S1.display();
    S1.changeLoc();
    S1.display();
cout<<"we are getting ready to call S1's destructor as we leave scope"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

super_test_2.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "super_impl.cpp"

int main()
{
    ///sptr is a location that can contain
    /// ONE thing...the address of a super
    super * sptr;
    ///we have an address..but no super..sooooo...
    ///using the alternate constructor

    sptr = new super;
    sptr ->setAlias("temp");
    sptr ->display();
    cout<<"before delete: "<<&sptr<<endl;
    ///the next line calls the destructor of the thing that
    ///sptr is pointing at...sptr is NOT deleted..how weird.
    delete sptr;
    cout<<"After delete: "<<&sptr<<endl;
    sptr = new super("Brian Ye","Proxy", "Save People", "no one knows");
    ///NOW we have a NEW super because sptr STILL EXISTS

    sptr->display();

    sptr->setIdent("Robby Williams");
    sptr->setAlias("Snail");
    sptr->setMState("To Protect Invertebrates Everywhere");
    sptr->setLocation("His secret lair under the rock");

    sptr->display();


   return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors

```
||=== Build: Debug in Simple Super Person Object (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
Z:\CS250\super.h|7|error: expected ')' before 'i'|
Z:\CS250\super.h|13|error: 'string' has not been declared|
Z:\CS250\super.h|14|error: 'string' has not been declared|
Z:\CS250\super.h|15|error: 'string' has not been declared|
Z:\CS250\super.h|16|error: 'string' has not been declared|
Z:\CS250\super.h|20|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|21|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|22|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|23|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|30|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|31|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|32|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h|33|error: 'string' does not name a type|
Z:\CS250\super.h||In destructor 'super::~super()':|
Z:\CS250\super.h|10|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super.h|10|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super.h||In member function 'void super::setIdent(int)':|
Z:\CS250\super.h|13|error: 'Ident' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super.h||In member function 'void super::setAlias(int)':|
Z:\CS250\super.h|14|error: 'Alias' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super.h||In member function 'void super::setMState(int)':|
Z:\CS250\super.h|15|error: 'MState' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super.h||In member function 'void super::setLocation(int)':|
Z:\CS250\super.h|16|error: 'Location' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp||In member function 'void super::display()':|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|11|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|11|error: 'Alias' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|11|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|12|error: 'Ident' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|13|error: 'MState' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|14|error: 'Location' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp||In member function 'void super::changeLoc()':|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|18|error: 'string' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|18|error: expected ';' before 'stemp'|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|19|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|19|error: 'Alias' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|19|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|20|error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|20|error: 'stemp' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|20|error: 'getline' was not declared in this scope|
Z:\CS250\super_impl.cpp|21|error: 'Location' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 34 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Helpful hint, always use `std::` instead of `using namespace std;` you'll learn whats in the `std` namespace and avoid errors like this ( as well as many other things but unrelated ).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the compilation errors. As an aside, including a .cpp file like that is not a normal thing to do. If you have implementation in a .cpp file, compile that separately and link to it.

Comment: @Serdalis I'm not doubting that having better effects, but because the professor wrote all this, I feel the solution to the error would be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

In `super.h` :

You should prefix all `string` occurrences by `std::`. Same thing for `cout` and `endl` that too come from the standard library. You should include the relevant headers in `super.h`.

You can also add header guards, to prevent multiple inclusions.

In `super_test_1.cpp`:

You want to include `super.h` and not `super_impl.cpp`. 
Why ? Because in case you include `super_impl.cpp` several times, multiple definitions of the same functions may cause issues.

Comment: The code was probably meant to have a "using namespace std" statement somewhere. It is a better solution to insert std:: in front of those standard library components, because this helps prevent namespace collisions, which can be tricky to diagnose. This is where you have two things with the same name.

Comment: Ok, so I used std:: for strings in h, and anything with iostream definitions like cout and endl. My error count shrunk significantly, but is it problematic to mix std:: and using namespace std in the same files?

Comment: Completely harmless. std:: prefixing just tells the compiler what namespace to use as an extra hint, if needed. Just like you did with `void super::display()`. "Hey, compiler! there's a method called `display` in `super`" Later you could have another `display` method in `uber` and with the namespacing the compiler can tell the two apart. If you want super's display, call `super::display`. For uber's display, `uber::display`.

Comment: @Tim Where `using namespace std;` becomes dangerous is everything that should be prefixed with std:: can now be referenced without and there is a lot of stuff in std that can have the same name as your stuff. The classic example is having to write a `reverse` function to reverse a string, common in early programming classes. But if `using namespace std;` has been used, `std::reverse` will also answer to `reverse`. Which `reverse` does the compiler use? Yours or the the library's? End result can be some really weird error messages.